# How to reference a cell with specifying some offset row where it should be shown

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following data...

[image]

...and I need to show it in the following format

[image]

Each cell in the second table is (obviously) taken from the first one, mostly using vlookup. My question is, how can I make each data to conditionally "skip" some rows. For example, Category "B" would need to skip 9 rows, because Category "A" used them all for 2 sub-categories and 7 stuffs that it has. Or Sub-Category "2" needs to skip 3 rows, etc.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible using formula, or is there any other approach to this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),unique(tocol(B2:B,1)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,c,
        reduce(tocol(,1),unique(filter(C:C,B:B=c)),lambda(f,q,vstack(f,hstack(,q),hstack(,,filter(A:A,B:B=c,C:C=q)))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: That works like magic. I don't understand any of those syntax haha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Its time-taking to create formulas *if data is provided via screenshots* since we've to manually type the data from screenshot & then create formulas as well! For future `1` You can easily share test data via this [table generator](https://markdown-convert.com/en/tool/table). Just paste the *data rows/columns* in this generator→press enter→then copy-paste the data here in the question as a table. `2` You can also share a test sheet using this [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) & is super recommended